# Countdown in Meteor + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, meteor

I am implementing a countdown for a task tracking application using Meteor and React. Here is the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import DetailTask from './DetailTask';
import {Meteor} from "meteor/meteor";
import moment from 'moment';


export default class Task extends React.Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        showComponent: false,
        startMessage: "",
        finishMessage: ""
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
        let myCursor = tasks.findOne({_id: this.props.task._id});
        let started = myCursor.started;
        if (started === true) {
            let finishTime = myCursor.finishTime;
            let myVar = setInterval(myCountdown, 1000);

            function myCountdown() {
                let now = moment().format('LTS');
                let start = moment.utc(now, "HH:mm:ss");
                let end = moment.utc(finishTime, "HH:mm:ss");
                let duration = moment.duration(end.diff(start));
                console.log(duration.hours(), duration.minutes(), duration.seconds());
                // here I should access the DOM
            }
        } else {
            console.log("This task hasn't started");
        }
    });
}

detailTask(e) {
    console.log('Now the detailed component will be displayed ');
    this.setState({
        showComponent: true,
    });
}

removeTask(e) {
    const taskId = this.props.task._id;
    //console.log(taskId);
    Meteor.call('tasks.remove', taskId);
}

startTask(e) {
    // first it updates the started field in the db
    // then it should make a call to a meteor function
    // passes the id of the task as argument
    // converts the duration to hours
    // and starts the countdown which will be provided
    // as an external file
    let myCursor = tasks.findOne({_id: this.props.task._id});
    let duration = myCursor.duration;
    console.log('Now the task should start');
    Meteor.call('tasks.started', this.props.task._id, duration);
    this.setState({
        startMessage: " Keep yourself productive. Don't forget, we are what we repeat ! "
    });
}

finishTask() {
    Meteor.subscribe('stats');
    console.log('Here you will finish the task manually');
    Meteor.call('tasks.finished', this.props.task._id);
    this.setState({
        finishMessage: " Nailed it ! "
    });
    Meteor.call('stats.insert', Meteor.userId(), this.props.task._id);
    // first it should update the finished field in the db
}

render() {
    return (
        <div key={this.props.task._id}>
            <p>Here the photo of the task will be.</p>
            <p>This is the task name: {this.props.task.taskName}</p>
            <p>This task has duration: {this.props.task.duration}</p>
            <button onClick={this.detailTask.bind(this)}>View Details</button>
            <button onClick={this.startTask.bind(this)}>Start Task</button>
            <button onClick={this.removeTask.bind(this)}>Remove Task</button>
            <button onClick={this.finishTask.bind(this)}>Finish Task</button>
            <p>Here the countdown will be displayed.</p>
            <div id="countdown">
                <div>
                    <h5>Hours</h5>
                    <span className="hours" ref={"hours"}>0</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h5>Minutes</h5>
                    <span className="minutes" ref={"minutes"}>0</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h5>Seconds</h5>
                    <span className="seconds" ref={"seconds"}>0</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            {this.state.showComponent ?
                <DetailTask id={this.props.task._id} taskName={this.props.task.taskName}/> :
                null}
            {this.state.startMessage ? <p>{this.state.startMessage}</p> :
                null}
            {this.state.finishMessage ? <p>{this.state.finishMessage}</p> :
                null}
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

My main concern is the **componentDidMount()** function. There I search for the particular task in the database, then I check if the task has started.
If so, I retrieve the expected finish time and calculate the difference between now and the expected finish time each second.I have console logged the countdown and it works for two different tasks. My question is how can I play with the DOM so that I can render the countdown for each task. I have created a countdown structure but I don't know how to access it. I tried using this.refs but it didn't work. Any ideas?